# Custom user model in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I know how to make custom user models, my question is about style and best practices.

What are the consequences of custom user model in Django? Is it really better to use auxiliary one-to-one model?

And for example if I have a `UserProfile` models which is one-to-one to `User`, should I create `friends` relationship (which would be only specific to my app) between `UserProfile` or between `User`?

Also all 3rd-party packages rely on `get_user_model()`, so looks like if I don't use custom user model, all your relations should go to `User`, right? But I still can't add methods to `User`, so if `User` has `friends` relation, and I want to add `recent_friends` method, I should add this method to `UserProfile`. This looks a bit inconsistent for me.

I'd be glad if someone experienced in Django could give a clear insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also all 3rd-party packages rely on get_user_model(), so looks like if I don't use custom user model, all your relations should go to User, right? But I still can't add methods to User, so if User has friends relation, and I want to add recent_friends method, I should add this method to UserProfile.

I have gone down the "one-to-one" route in the past and I ended up not liking the design of my app at all, it seems to me that it forces you away from SOLID. So if I was you I would rather subclass `AbstractBaseUser` or `AbstractUser`.

With `AbstractBaseUser` you are provided just the core implementation of `User` and then you can extend the model according to your requirements.
Depending on what sort of 3rd-party packages you are using you might need more than just the core implementation: if that's the case just extend `AbstractUser` which lets you extend the complete implementation of `User`.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely recommend using a custom user model - even if you use a one-to-one with a profile. It is incredibly hard to migrate to a custom user model if you've committed to the default user model, and there's almost always a point where you want to add at least some custom logic to the user model.

Whether you use a profile or further extend the user model should then be based on all considerations that usually apply to your database structure. The right™  decision depends on the exact details of your profile, which only you know.